# How to format the cells of a bound DataGrid based on the values provided by a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, formatting

I am developing my first WPF Application, so I am not seasoned at all on WPF. I have the following situation:

I have a window that has a `DataGrid` control. The constructor of the window receives a `DataTable` as input. The `Window` class is as follows:

```
public partial class Project_Status_Window : Window {

        //Required for the datacontext
        public DataTable status { get; }

        public Project_Status_Window(DataTable status) {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.status = status;
            this.Show();
        }
    }
```

In order to display the table I am binding the status table in my XAML description of the window. As follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Status_Table_Viewer" ItemsSource="{Binding status.DefaultView}"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="1"
                  SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
```

Now I want to change the background of the cells in one column (preferably selecting the column by name). However the background should be changed only if the value in the cells is contained in a list that is populated through a method that in turn invokes a database query. Since this is presentation logic I would like to keep it on the XAML side. I have been researching a lot and cannot find a similar case, though I believe that this can be done with `DataTrigger`s, so I have the following code in XAML:

```
              <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True"> I have no Idea what to write in this tag
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
              </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Let's assume that the window will have a method that receives a string as input and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the string is missing in the database or not. The method will be the following:

```
public bool isMissingMat(string input)
```

I don't know how to access the data in a named column of my `DataTable`, pass the data to my custom method and then act on the formatting of the `DataGrid` based on the value of my method.

Comment: What column and what value?

Comment: @mm8 the column name is "Work Order" and the values that it takes are 5 digit integers in string format. e.g 58307 the method isMissingMat decides of the string value will return true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you want to achieve. Unfortunately, getting formatting working for a DataGrid is devilishly difficult and cannot be explained here to you step by step. Better just read my article [CodeProject: Guide to WPF DataGrid formatting using bindings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings). It gives a lot of background information which you even cannot find on MSDN :-(

It has also a sample how you can change the background colour of a row based on business logic data, precisely what you need.

You wrote: "Since this is presentation logic I would like to keep it on the XAML side." That is not a good idea. XAML is good at defining static content, but horribly bad at doing simple logical stuff, like it can even not do addition or if-statements or debugging or ... Your life is MUCH easier, when you do dynamic stuff in code behind. Again, see my article to get a feeling what you should do in XAML and what is better done in code behind.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. However I solved the issue with a workaround. First I declared all the visible columns in XAML. Then I added a new column of data based on the said method.I then used a datatrigger to set the background color as I wanted.